# PostgreSQL Entity Framework Code First Migration generating new table for object type JSONB field

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am using .net core 3.1

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    **[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]**
    public IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }      
}

public class Address
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

But, when I ran add migration command that generating new table for Addresses, that I don't want
I just want to capture address list in jsonb format but not in separate table.

I am using fluent api for configuration (just for understanding above class is decorated), do we have any property where I can specify to not generate new table for any object type property.

I tried -  [NotMapped]  but this ignore that specific column entirely

Thank you!